# Why is variable declaration not allowed here?

Tags: go

Why does `testC()` fail to compile in the following go code? I would expect that the behavior would match that of `testB()` with the exception that `err`'s scope would be limited to the if block.

The error message provided by the compiler is `resp declared and not used`

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    testA()
    testB()
    testC()
    testD()
}

// valid
func testA() {
    resp, err := generateInt()
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Resp=%v Error=%v", resp, err))
}

// valid
func testB() {
    var resp *int
    resp, err := generateInt()
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Resp=%v Error=%v", resp, err))
}

// does not compile
func testC() {
    var resp *int
    if resp, err := generateInt(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error=%v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Resp=%d", *resp)
}

// valid
func testD() {
    var resp *int
    var err error
    if resp, err = generateInt(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error=%v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Resp=%d", *resp)
}

func generateInt() (*int, error) {
    result := 5
    return &result, nil
}
```

Comment: this is because you are not using an internal variable,right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example:

```
var resp *int
if resp, err := generateInt(); err != nil {
```

The [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) is redeclaring the `resp` variable. Because an if's statement is scoped to the inside the if block, it only shadows the first `resp` variable within that block, leaving the first unused.